# Print custom invoice of page size (20.5 x 14 cm) using jasper report or iText for Java

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, report, itext

I want to print data on invoice receipt size of 20.5 x 14 cm(hard copy). In which I try to put text at some absolute location. I tried iText first. In that I try to set page size by following code.

```
    // here what is unite used in bracket of rectangle?

    Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(552,377));


    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("report.pdf"));
    document.open();
    ...
    ...
    ...
    document.close();
```

Second I tried Jasper report. In that I set page size to 20.5 x 14 cm. But how can I take value from my java application's textfield and put it in to some absolute location in iReport.

As I know jasper report take value from database but how can I take value from java application's textfiled?

I am more familiar with iText.

I will be thankful to any developer who can guide me how can I print custom invoice using iText or Jasper Report.I am developing java application using netbeans.

Comment: About the second question, usually the iResport tool (Jasper Reports environment in general) would work with "data sources". You can create a data source from CSV files, from databases and even from Java Beans. How can you export, from your application, the data you want to show on the reports?

Comment: Thank you Gustavo Meria for replying. Actually as I know I can pass just sql query that can show data on ireport using data source provided to iReport. But I don't know that it's possible or not exporting data from application like from text field or etc. to iReport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of a page in PDF is defined by the MediaBox (required). The visible area is defined by the CropBox (optional). The measurement unit in PDF is the *user unit*. By default 1 user unit coincides with 1 point. In other words: 1 inch = 72 user units.

However, one can define a UserUnit value between 1 and 75,000. You won't find that much PDFs that change the default and as you're creating a PDF from scratch, you are using the default user unit. In your case, a page that measures 552 by 377 user units, is 7.66 by 5.24 inch or 19.47 by 13.30 cm. You need a `Rectangle` of 581.10 by 396.85 user units:

```
new Rectangle(581.1f, 396.85f);
```

I am not at all familiar with JasperReports, so I can only answer the first part of your question regarding the measurement system. Maybe you can post a second question that focuses on the JasperReports part of your question.

Comment: Hi Bruno Lowagie, Thank you for fast reply. I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. In `iReport -> Report Inspektor -> right click on "report name" -> Page Format` 
   (also you might need to go to Tools -> Options -> iReport -> General -> Units, you can change the default units of measurement... and mm is an option.)
   The jrxml output should look smthg like this:

   jasperReport
    name="networth_p200"
    orientation="Landscape"
    pageWidth="842"
    pageHeight="595"

2. Take a look at these for passing parameters from a Java app:
[JasperReports parameters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_parameters.htm) & [Passing params to Jasper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGk1r3Gn4to)

Comment: Hi Endrik, Thank you for instant reply. I seen youtube video and tutorial point site. I got it.Thank you.